# Answer for Battleships Lieutenant Level 16

Tags: ios, battleships

Does anyone know the answer for Lieutenant Level 16 of the Battleships puzzle game for the iPhone? I'm stuck. I got all the other levels and I can't advance without figuring out this one.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone - is it similar to [this game](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2011/01/classic_battleships_light.php)? If so, you may want to just show us the level - that way, it would still be possible to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the trick:

```
o----o-2 Line 1
-------0 Line 2
-----o-1 Line 3
-----o-1 Line 4
-------0 Line 5
--ooo-o4 Line 6
o-----02 Line 7
2011132
```